# code that works gets 0 key error when iterate it

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, global-variables, keyerror

When I run below code, it works

```
df[df['column1'].isin([data['column2'][0]])]['column3'][0]
```

But when I iterate it as below, it gives key error 0

```
newlist2=[]
for i in datalist: 
    newlist2.append(df[df['column1'].isin([globals()[i]['column2'][0]])]['column3'][0])
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [67], in <cell line: 4>()
      3 newlist2=[]
      4 for i in datalist: 
----> 5     newlist2.append(mergeddata[mergeddata['DATE_OF_RESTRUCTURE'].isin([**globals()[i]['REPORT_DATE'][0]**])]['CONTRACT_NUMBER'][0])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The possible reason why you're getting a key error is when the column information for that particular row isn't as complete as the others before it.

Comment: Provide your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split following code into four parts

```
df[df['column1'].isin([globals()[i]['column2'][0]])]['column3'][0]
```

1. Condition check: `Series.isin()`.
2. Boolean indexing: `df[boolean]`
3. Column selection: `sub_df['column3']`
4. Index selection: `column3[0]`

When the `Series.isin()` returns all `False` and you do boolean indexing with it. This will cause the `sub_df` empty so your `[0]` indexing will through indexing error.